# How to count the comma separated value using sql server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hi i have create one function for getting the count of comma separated string and making the one string using this function. but with my code i have not getting proper result. 
This is my function :

```
  alter FUNCTION GetString
    ( 
       @Parm nvarchar(max)
    )
    RETURNS varchar(max) 
    AS
    BEGIN

     DECLARE @str nvarchar(max) 
      declare @Catcount int = (select LEN(@Parm) - LEN(REPLACE(@Parm, ',', '')) + 1)

    if(@Catcount = 2 )
      BEGIN
     select @str =  @Parm + ' other categories you follow.'
      END
      else if(@Catcount > 2 )
      BEGIN
        select @str =  @Parm + ' and ' + CAST(@Catcount - 2 AS NVARCHAR(10)) + ' 
    other categories you follow.'
      END
     RETURN @str
     END
     GO
```

here i have run this function =>

```
select dbo.GetString('cricket,swim,eating')
```

This is my current output

```
 cricket,swim,eating and 1 other categories you follow.
```

My expected output is

```
cricket,swim and 1 other categories you follow.
```

Can anyone help me to identify error and please let me know how can i fix it

Comment: SQL Serfe4r 2016 already has a `STRING_SPLIT`. There are several dozen duplicate questions that show how to split a string with T-SQL. What you tried is one of the slowest possible methods. Check [Aaron Bertrand's articles](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings) on string splitting. The *fastest* method is to use a SQLCLR function. Second fastest is to use XML

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos but here i don't want to split the string please see my expacted output and please let me know how can do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to remove characters after second comma. Try something like this in your @Catcount>2 block:

```
else if(@Catcount > 2 )
    BEGIN
        declare @firstComma INT = (select CHARINDEX(',',@parm))
        Declare @secondComma INT = (select CHARINDEX(',', SUBSTRING(@parm, @firstComma+1, LEN(@parm))) + @firstComma)
        select @str = SUBSTRING(@parm,1, @secondComma-1) + ' and ' + CAST(@Catcount - 2 AS NVARCHAR(10)) + ' other catgeroris you follow.'
    END
```

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing your second select with..

```
select @str =  LEFT(@Parm, Charindex(',',substring(@Parm,charindex(',',@Parm)+1,
len(@Parm))) +charindex(',',@Parm) -1) + ' and ' + 
CAST(@Catcount - 2 AS NVARCHAR(10)) + ' other catgeroris you follow.'
```

I don't think counting comma's is the best way to do this and would say splitting the string would be better.  However this select looks for the second comma and returns only the first two categories in the list..

Answer (score 0):

As other answers suggests, your problem is this row:

```
select @str =  @Parm + ' and ' + CAST(@Catcount - 2 AS NVARCHAR(10)) + 
' other catgeroris you follow.'
```

I would use [`STUFF`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/stuff-transact-sql) to replace the part of `@Parm` after the second comma:

```
SELECT @str = STUFF(@Parm, 
                    CHARINDEX(',', @Parm, CHARINDEX(',', @Parm)+1),
                    LEN(@Parm), 
                    ' and ' + CAST(@Catcount - 2 AS NVARCHAR(10)) + ' other catgeroris you follow.')
```

Also, I've made some minor changes to the function (coding style, nothing meaningful).

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GetString
( 
   @Parm nvarchar(max)
)
RETURNS varchar(max) 
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @str nvarchar(max), 
            @Catcount int = (LEN(@Parm) - LEN(REPLACE(@Parm, ',', '')) + 1)

    IF @Catcount = 2 
    BEGIN
        SELECT @str =  @Parm + ' other catgeroris you follow.'
    END
    ELSE IF @Catcount > 2 
    BEGIN
        SELECT @str = STUFF(@Parm, CHARINDEX(',', @Parm, CHARINDEX(',', @Parm)+1), LEN(@Parm), ' and ' + CAST(@Catcount - 2 AS NVARCHAR(10)) + ' other catgeroris you follow.')
    END
    RETURN @str
END
GO
```

[You can see a live demo on rextester.](http://rextester.com/HLGH54222)